# Split into column treating successive delimiters as one

Tags: r, regex, string, split, tidyr

Hi I would like to split one column of a data.frame into multiple columns but with successive delimiters treated as one. My input has been scraped from a text file so is a bit of a mess with different delimiters and sometimes the same one duplicated multiple times. In my example below I am using space, comma, 
"and" or dash as the delimiters but I actually have >6 different ones including several words ("and" and "incl").

I would normally use `tidyr::separate` but it doesn't have an option combine successive delimiters. Trying to make an exhaustive list of the possible combinations for the pattern soon gets ridiculous especially as sometimes I might have 4 or 5 spaces or commas in a row.

I have provided a reprex and desired output (made by manually changing the text which is not feasible in my real data of 1000s of lines) below

***Data:***

```r
library(tidyr)

testdf <- data.frame(test = c("This string has single spaces",
                              "This  one  has  double  spaces",
                              "This, has, comma,or space,   or ,both",
                              "This,one-, space,- comma -,and-dash"))
```

***These are the codes I have tried to use so far:***

```r
separate(testdf, test, into = letters[1:12], sep = " |,|-|and", fill = "right")

#> Warning: Expected 12 pieces. Additional pieces discarded in 2 rows [3, 4].
#>      a      b   c      d      e     f      g    h      i     j    k    l
#> 1 This string has single spaces  <NA>   <NA> <NA>   <NA>  <NA> <NA> <NA>
#> 2 This        one           has       double      spaces  <NA> <NA> <NA>
#> 3 This        has               comma     or             space          
#> 4 This        one               space                    comma
```

```r
#sort of starting to work but gets very extensive very fast
separate(testdf, test, into = letters[1:12], sep = "  |, |, | |and|,", fill = "right")

#>      a      b    c      d      e    f     g     h    i     j    k    l
#> 1 This string  has single spaces <NA>  <NA>  <NA> <NA>  <NA> <NA> <NA>
#> 2 This    one  has double spaces <NA>  <NA>  <NA> <NA>  <NA> <NA> <NA>
#> 3 This    has       comma     or            space         or      both
#> 4 This        one-  space      -      comma     -      -dash <NA> <NA>
```

***Based on Gregor's answer before I specified I needed word delimiters:***

```r
separate(testdf, test, into = letters[1:12], sep = "[ ,-]+", fill = "right")
#>      a      b        c      d      e     f    g    h    i    j    k    l
#> 1 This string      has single spaces  <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
#> 2 This    one      has double spaces  <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
#> 3 This    has andcomma     or    and space   or both <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
#> 4 This    one    space    and  comma   and dash <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
```

````r
###*Desired Output:*
```r
#>      a      b     c      d      e    f    g
#> 1 This string   has single spaces <NA> <NA>
#> 2 This    one   has double spaces <NA> <NA>
#> 3 This    has comma     or  space   or both
#> 4 This    one space  comma    dash <NA> <NA>
````

<sup>Created on 2019-10-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: `\\s+|,|-` only hands the multi spaces not the combinations or multiples of the others.

Comment: I'm confused by your update - if `and` is a delimiter, why is it still in your desired result (row 4)?

Comment: Oh, that's a typo/me not being thorough in making my desired output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex pattern `[ ,\\-]` matches a space, a comma, or a dash. Adding a `+` quantifier makes it match one or more spaces, commas, or dashes. This is the pattern you should use. (We escape the dash `-` because inside brackets, it can be a special character, e.g., `"[a-z]"` matches all lower-case letters. Make sure you escape any other special regex characters in your pattern.)

```
tidyr::separate(testdf, test, into = letters[1:12], sep = "[ ,\\-]+", fill = "right")
#      a      b     c      d      e    f    g    h    i    j    k    l
# 1 This string   has single spaces <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
# 2 This    one   has double spaces <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
# 3 This    has comma     or  space   or both <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
# 4 This    one space  comma    and dash <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
```

> I would normally use `tidyr::separate` but it doesn't have an option combine successive delimiters

Actually, the default `sep` does combine successive delimiters. The default pattern is `[^[:alnum:]]+`, which is one or more non-alpanumeric characters. For this sample data, everything present that's not a letter is a delimiter, so the default works just fine (but, of course, your real data may be more complicated and may include punctuation that you *don't* want to separate on, so the approach at the top is what you want).

```
tidyr::separate(testdf, test, into = letters[1:12], fill = "right")
# same output as above
```

If you want to be fancy, use `stringr::str_count` to count the max number of delimiters and define `into` accordingly:

```
my_pattern = "[ ,\\-]+"
max_delim = max(stringr::str_count(testdf$test, pattern = my_pattern))
tidyr::separate(testdf, test, into = letters[1:(max_delim + 1)],
  fill = "right", sep = my_pattern)
#      a      b     c      d      e    f    g
# 1 This string   has single spaces <NA> <NA>
# 2 This    one   has double spaces <NA> <NA>
# 3 This    has comma     or  space   or both
# 4 This    one space  comma    and dash <NA>
```

For multicharacter matches, you can use `()` with `|` for or, like `"(,| |-|and|incl)+"`.

Comment: Thanks this looks handy, but I should have included that one of my delimiters is the word 'and' and one is 'incl' is there some one to add a word to this as well? I will update my question to reflect this

Comment: In that case you can use a pattern like this: `"( |,|-|and|incl)+"`

Comment: Sweet  `"( |,|-|and|incl)+"` works. Do you understand why for this I use round brackets with plus after but the original answer used []? [] doesn't work with the words. If you modify your answer to include `"( |,|-|and|incl)+"` I'll accept it.

Comment: Square brackets are for matching *single characters*. `[xyz]` is a shorthand for `(x|y|z)`, but only single characters are allowed. When you added the requirement for multicharacter matches, we had to move to the longer syntax.